# SQL Server : output only one Postage Cost Against an Order with Multiple Line Items

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am querying orders;

```
Order#   Customer     Item     Postage
11111    Customer1    Item1    £3.99
11112    Customer2    Item1    £3.99
11112    Customer2    Item2    £3.99
11112    Customer2    Item3    £3.99
```

My problem is for each order I only want to output one postage cost.  In the above example, 11112 is outputting three postage costs.

Desired result;

```
Order#   Customer     Item     Postage
11111    Customer1    Item1    £3.99
11112    Customer2    Item1    
11112    Customer2    Item2    
11112    Customer2    Item3    £3.99
```

Can anyone direct me to some documentation or provide from sample SELECT queries for dealing with this problem?

I have simplified the question and output, for those that would like to look at the actual Database structure, I have attached an image of the order table (Linnworks), ignore the Postal Services table it has no relevance to the question.

[image: Linnworks Order Table]

Comment: *For each order I only want to output one postage cost* ... which one?

Comment: can you show your query ?

Comment: The query is rather large and would just over complicate the question.  I will update the question to show a desired result?!

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do what you want with `row_number()`:

```
with q as (
      <your query here>
     )
select OrderNum, Customer, Item,
       (case when seqnum = 1 then postage end) as Postage
from (select q.*,
             row_number() over (partition by ordernum order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from q
     ) q;
```

Comment: This looks interesting and might just be what I am looking for.  I will update.